# Install new library without reinstalling cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I need to install jq under Text library in cygwin without reinstalling it, is there any way to update libraries or install new ones without reinstalling cygwin?

thanks.

I opened preinstalled cygwin, it takes me through installing steps which may overwrite my installed libraries.

Comment: You can use the `setup.exe` app from `cygwin.com` (which you used to install cygwin) to update and install new packages. You should download the latest version of `setup.exe` for the best results. The `jq` package is available at version 1.6 now. The setup app offers to install all out of date packages, leave those packages checked to update them. Change the drop down that says `Pending` to `Full`, and put `jq` in the search box. In the row starting with `jq`, use the drop down in the `New` column to pick the version you want to install.